# Error al momento de dar doble click en mi datagridview

Tags: c#, sql-server

tengo un problema con este script. Al momento de dar doble click, me devuelven los datos normales pero hay algunos campos donde le faltan algunos datos por ejemplo, algunas fechas u otro campo más. Como podría hacer para que cuando le de doble click me traiga los datos aún así falten datos porque me salta error... Lo estoy haciendo en C# con Sql Server, los datos lo traigo de mi BD

```
private void dgvDatos_CellMouseDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.RowIndex != -1)
        {
            DataGridViewCellCollection cells = dgvDatos.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells;
            frmProveedor.ACM1PT.cod_proveedor = int.Parse(cells[0].Value.ToString());
            frmProveedor.ACM1PT.txtSiaf.Text = cells[1].Value.ToString();
            frmProveedor.ACM1PT.txtProveedor.Text = cells[2].Value.ToString();
            frmProveedor.ACM1PT.cboUe.SelectedValue = cells[3].Value.ToString();
            frmProveedor.ACM1PT.txtNOrden.Text = cells[5].Value.ToString();
            frmProveedor.ACM1PT.cboOficina.SelectedValue = cells[6].Value.ToString();
            frmProveedor.ACM1PT.txtSinad.Text = cells[8].Value.ToString();
            frmProveedor.ACM1PT.txtSiga.Text = cells[9].Value.ToString();
            frmProveedor.ACM1PT.dtpFecha.Value = Convert.ToDateTime(cells[10].Value.ToString());
            frmProveedor.ACM1PT.cboTarea.SelectedValue = cells[11].Value.ToString();
            frmProveedor.ACM1PT.txtRecursos.Text = cells[13].Value.ToString();
            frmProveedor.ACM1PT.cboUMedida.SelectedValue = cells[14].Value.ToString();
            frmProveedor.ACM1PT.cboFf.SelectedValue = cells[16].Value.ToString();
            frmProveedor.ACM1PT.cboClasificador.SelectedValue = cells[18].Value.ToString();
            frmProveedor.ACM1PT.txtCantidad.Text = cells[20].Value.ToString();
            frmProveedor.ACM1PT.txtUnitario.Text = cells[21].Value.ToString();
            frmProveedor.ACM1PT.txtTotal.Text = cells[22].Value.ToString();
            //frmProveedor.ACM1PT.dtpInicio.Value = Convert.ToDateTime(cells[23].Value.ToString());
            //frmProveedor.ACM1PT.dtpFin.Value = Convert.ToDateTime(cells[24].Value.ToString());
            frmProveedor.ACM1PT.txtObservacion.Text = cells[25].Value.ToString();
            frmProveedor.ACM1PT.desBotones(false, true);
            frmProveedor.ACM1PT.btnRegistrar.Text = "&Actualizar";
            frmProveedor.ACM1PT.desCajas(true);
            frmProveedor.ACM1PT.actualizar = true;
            this.Close();
        }
    }
```

Este es el error que me sale, es cuando le doy doble click y no encuentra el campo fecha, ya que algunos no tienen...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
La excepción se generó originalmente en esta pila de llamadas:
System.DateTimeParse.Parse(string, System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles)
System.Convert.ToDateTime(string)
MINEDU_ESCALAFON.V1.Vistas.frmBuscarProveedor.dgvDatos_CellMouseDoubleClick(object, System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs) en frmBuscarProveedor.cs
System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.OnCellMouseDoubleClick(System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs)
System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.OnMouseDoubleClick(System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs)
System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message, System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons, int)
System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message)
System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(System.IntPtr, int, System.IntPtr, System.IntPtr)
System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(System.IntPtr, int, int)
...
[Pila de llamadas truncada]
```

Comment: Ya agregué la foto del error, espero que me puedas ayudar. Gracias.

Comment: Pues a simple vista... el error es claro esta fallando el casteo de String a DateTime

Comment: Exacto, el error es que no hay datos que completen los campos para pasar, por eso estoy buscando como poder llevar aún así los campos estén vacíos para que pasen los datos a mi formulario

Answer (score 0):

Hola: dtpFecha supongo que será un datetimePicker, y en WindowsForms esto no admite valores null, pero si puedes ponerle si viene un null, el valór mínimo (1 de enero de 1753), o algo del estilo.

```
 frmProveedor.ACM1PT.dtpFecha.Value = cells[10].Value == null ? dptFecha.MinValue : Convert.ToDateTime(cells[10].Value.ToString());
```

Comment: Trate de ponerlo así pero me sale error en "DateTimePicker" no contiene un definición para "MinValue" ni un método de extensión accesible "MinValue" que acepte un primer argumento del tipo "DateTimePicker"

Comment: Olvide que no es solo en ese campo, también en otros campos quizás no haya datos, sería mejor poner un case creo para que recorra todas las lineas y llenarlas con espacios en blanco

Comment: Eso estaría bien, pero los objetos tipo datetimePicker, no puedes rellenarlos con un espacio en blanco. Puedes utilizar el operador ternario como te he puesto en el ejemplo. celss[x].value==null?'':Convert....

Comment: No es MinValue es MinDate. Hacerlo de memoria, a veces es lo que tiene. :)